# Remove nav class with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, devexpress

Want to remove the class with jQuery but it doesn't work. please advise me.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#MainMenu").removeClass("clearfix");
  });
</script>

<nav class="dxbs-menu clearfix" id="MainMenu">
  <ul class="text-bars nav navbar-nav">
  </ul>
</nav>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJ8WB.png)

Comment: Are their any error messages that show up in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Place the JavaScript below, followed by it inspects the element to check that the class has actually been removed.

If that doesn't work out I recommend you use toogleclass and play with a display style: None

Comment: Thank u for advice me. it to work when add class navbar-header
<div class="navbar-header">
                    <dx:BootstrapMenu ID="MainMenu" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="MainMenu">

Answer (score 0):

I using Devexpress BootstrapMenu when design time clearfix class invisible when run time found class clearfix while inspecting element. Want to remove class clearfix.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for advice me. it to work when add class to div